# python - sqlite3 returning wrong results

Tags: python, sqlite

If I run this query directly in sqlite3.exe on the same database, I get 20 records.

When I run it in Python using sqlite3, it returns every single record from table a (200000+).

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect("path/to/my.db")
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("""SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* FROM t_data a NATURAL LEFT JOIN t_finished b
            NATURAL LEFT JOIN user_info c WHERE user_id=1;""")
for row in c:
    print row
```

How can this be possible?

---

Here is how the tables are related.

```
CREATE TABLE t_data ( t_id INTEGER  REFERENCES t_finished (t_id),
    ui_id INTEGER  NOT NULL  REFERENCES user_info (ui_id), ...);

CREATE TABLE t_finished ( t_id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY, ...);

CREATE TABLE user_info ( ui_id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY, user_id INTEGER  REFERENCES accounts, ...);
```

No other columns are shared between them.

---

Trying to use explicit JOINS I have the same problem:

```
SELECT * FROM t_data a LEFT JOIN t_finished b USING(t_id) LEFT JOIN user_info c USING(ui_id) WHERE user_id=1;
```

This query works in sqlite3.exe, but throws an error in Python:

```
OperationalError: cannot join using column ui_id - column not present in both tables
```

Comment: Any chance you can give us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) dataset? I certainly cannot reproduce your issue locally with some test data.

Comment: Are you certain that no columns were added to the database? A `NATURAL JOIN` is [prone to producing very different results](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Natural_join) when you do that..

Comment: Unfortunately the data is confidential or I'd share the database.

Comment: If you are getting an error on the column not being present, then you are **not** using the same database.

Comment: Long shot: your sqlite library is outdated. What does `sqlite.sqlite_version` print? And what does `sqlite3.exe -version` tell you the command-line version uses?

Comment: I am opening the same database in Python sqlite3 and sqlite3.exe. They must be incompatible in some way.

Comment: Python 3.6.12, exe 3.7.13. Maybe this is the cause.

Comment: This is rather a major difference in behaviour; other than *Enhanced robustness against corrupt database files* I see no [obvious entries in the version history](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) that explain the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: I updated sqlite3.dll in Python (to the lastest 3.8 version) and it now works as expected! Crazy. Thanks for the help. Do you want to submit the answer?

Comment: Not so long a shot then, after all. Posted an answer for you. And apologies for the skepticism towards the database being the same, that is the most common problem with SQLite discrepancies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are 100% certain that you are dealing with the same database, you probably are using a newer SQLite library version with the command-line tool.

You can verify what versions are being used with:

```
print sqlite.sqlite_version
```

in Python and

```
sqlite3 -version
```

with the command-line tool. You can check against the [sqlite3 changelog](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) to see if anything relevant changed, or you could just update your SQLite3 DLLs to the lastest version to make sure that you are not running into a bug or new feature here.